# Apache Wicket 6.x to 9.1/9.2 migration, AJAX com.googlecode.wicket.kendo.ui.form.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField stopped working

Tags: jquery, wicket

I used `com.googlecode.wicket.kendo.ui.form.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField` with Apache Wicket 6.x. It is added in a WebMarkupContainer in the `onBeforeRender()`.
I migrated to Wicket 9.1 including Wicket JQuery UI 9.1.

I also tried a combination Wicket 9.2 and Wicket JQuery UI 9.1 (9.2 is not available in the Maven Central Repository).

The rendering of the HTML works fine, but there are these problems

- the Javascript that gets the autocomplete choices from the server starts working only after the page is reloaded e.g. by clicking the reload button of the browser
- the Javascript that should be called when a choice is selected is not called at all

I compared the AJAX Javascript between Wicket 6.x and 9.1. It seems that the component paths in the new version are a bit broken but didn't find why.

In this part there is missing number after 3-

```
"read": "./solution-edit?3-.0-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server&id=1"
```

In this part all the other paths in the AJAX response have 3-1.0 instead of 3-1.1.

```
"u":"./solution-edit?3-1.1-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server&id=1","
```

The 6.x

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="kendo-id3a1_datasource">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function() { window.id3a1_datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ "serverFiltering": true, "dataType": "json", "transport": { "read": "./solution-edit?7-1.IBehaviorListener.0-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server" }, "error": function (xhr, error) { var dw = Wicket.Ajax.DebugWindow; if (typeof dw !== 'undefined') { dw.logError(kendo.stringify(xhr)); } }, "sync": function() { this.read(); } }); });
/*]^]^>*/
</script>


(function(){jQuery('#id3a1').kendoAutoComplete({ "template": jQuery('#id3a1_template').html(), "select": function (e) {
var attrs = {"u":"./solution-edit?7-1.IBehaviorListener.1-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server","c":"id3a1"};
var params = [{"name":"index","value":e.item.index()},{"name":"value","value":e.item.text}]^;
attrs.ep = params.concat(attrs.ep || []^);
Wicket.Ajax.ajax(attrs);
}
, "dataTextField": "supportString", "autoBind": true, "dataSource": window.id3a1_datasource });})();
```

The 9.1

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="kendo-platformSizing_platform_serverf7_datasource">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function() { window.platformSizing_platform_serverf7_datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ "serverFiltering": true, "dataType": "json", "transport": { "read": "./solution-edit?3-.0-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server&id=1" }, "error": function (xhr, error) { var dw = Wicket.Ajax.DebugWindow; if (typeof dw !== 'undefined') { dw.logError(kendo.stringify(xhr)); } }, "sync": function() { this.read(); } }); });
/*]]]]><![CDATA[>*/
</script>

(function(){jQuery('#platformSizing_platform_serverf7').kendoAutoComplete({ "template": jQuery('#platformSizing_platform_serverf7_template').html(), "select": function (e) {
var attrs = {"u":"./solution-edit?3-1.1-solutionForm-phaseForm-tabs-panel-form-selectedSizing-sizingConfiguration-platformSizing.platform.server&id=1","c":"platformSizing_platform_serverf7"};
var params = [{"name":"index","value":e.item.index()},{"name":"value","value":e.item.text}];
attrs.ep = params.concat(attrs.ep || []);
Wicket.Ajax.ajax(attrs);
}
, "dataTextField": "supportString", "autoBind": true, "dataSource": window.platformSizing_platform_serverf7_datasource });})();
```

Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head><title>Demo</title></head>
    <body>
        <form wicket:id="form">
            <span wicket:id="label"/>
            <div wicket:id="container">
                <span wicket:id="panel"></span>
           </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Panel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
            <input wicket:id="autocomplete" type="text" style="width: 500px;"/>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Page

```
public class CustomPage extends WebPage {
    
     private  IModel<String> model = new Model();

     protected void onInitialize() {
         super.onInitialize();

         Form<String> form = new Form<>("form", model);
         Label label = new Label("label", "Click");
         label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
         label.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("click") {
        
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if (model.getObject() == null) {
                    model.setObject("data");
                } else {
                    model.setObject(null);
                }
                target.add(getForm());
            }

            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(getForm());
            }
       
            protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
                super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

                attributes.setEventPropagation(EventPropagation.STOP);
            }
         });

         form.add(label);
         Container container = new Container("container", model);
         form.add(container);
         add(form);
     }  
}
```

Container

```
public class Container extends WebMarkupContainer {
    public Container(String id, IModel<?> model) {
       super(id, model);
       setOutputMarkupId(true);
    }
    protected void onBeforeRender() {
       Object obj = getDefaultModelObject();
       IModel<?> model = getDefaultModel();

       if (obj != null) {
           addOrReplace(new CustomPanel("panel", model));
       } else {
           addOrReplace(new Label("panel", ""));
       }

       super.onBeforeRender();
    }
}
```

Panel

```
public class CustomPanel extends Panel {

     public CustomPanel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
         super(id, model);
         setOutputMarkupId(true);
         add(new CustomAutoComplete("autocomplete"));
     }

    private class CustomAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextField<String> {

        public CustomAutoComplete(String id) {
            super(id);
            setOutputMarkupId(true);
        }

        protected List<String> getChoices(String input) {

            // In reality the data is read from DB.
            List<String> choices = List.of("c1", "c2");

            return choices;
        }

        protected void onSelected(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(getForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The jQuery is not easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Wicket 9.2.0 first, in the prior version a regression broke JS loading.

Comment: Actually that's what I did (I updated the question), the same problem remains, but because Wicket JQuery UI has the highest version 9.1, I described it that way.

Comment: Can you create a quickstart? Hard to spot the error from the code you've given.

Comment: I added some HTML and Java files but they are simplified and reduced to give the main idea.